# How to navigate to a page in Framework7

Tags: javascript, routes, html-framework-7

I am just starting with Framework7 and I want to navigate to another page when a click a paragraph. I tried a few things and googled for the past hour but no luck.

Here is the code I have in **my-app.js**:

```
var $$ = Dom7;

var app = new Framework7({
    // App root element
    root: '#app',
    // App Name
    name: 'My App',
    // App id
    id: 'com.myapp.test',
    // Enable swipe panel
    panel: {
      swipe: 'left',
    },
    view : {
        stackPages: true
    },
    // Add default routes
    routes: [
      {
        name: 'about',
        path: '/about/',
        url: 'about.html',
      },
      {
        name: 'index',
        path: '/index/',
        url: 'index.html'
      },
      {
        name: 'preview',
        path: '/preview/',
        url: './preview.html'
      },
    ],
    // ... other parameters
  });

 var mainView = app.views.create('.view-main');
 $$('p').on('click', function(){
     mainView.router.navigate('/preview/');
 });
```

When I click a paragraph nothing happens and there are no errors when I run the inspector.
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by using this:

```
self.app.router.navigate('/preview/', {reloadCurrent: true});
```

Also make sure that html layout like this:

```
<div class="view">
    <!-- Initial Page, "data-name" contains page name -->
    <div data-name="preview" class="page">
        <!-- Scrollable page content -->
        <div class="page-content">
           preview page content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update 1: In F7 ver 4 you can use this:**

```
app.views.main.router.navigate('/login/', {reloadCurrent: true});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had a cross origin error at first but now I am running a simple server and its working! Cheers!

Comment: Nice squeekyDave, Welcome any time :D

Comment: this path app.views.main.router will return undefined in the newest versions. Something probably changed because when you print the app variable console.log(app.views.main), it returns null or undefined. Plus the main.router does not exist. If you print console.log(app), you can see all that is available and navigate isn't a method anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.mainView.router.navigate('/preview/')
```

Try this if the answer @Anis offered but its supposed to work that answer

Answer (score 0):

It should work using : `app.router.navigate('/preview/')`

Answer (score 0):

To go some specific routes you can use

```
app.views.main.router.navigate('your route');
```

If you have a scenario like after create some task and you have to redirect to listing page, where if you use

```
if(formSubmitSuccessfull){
     app.views.main.router.navigate('your router')
}
```

It will redirect to the previous page (In this case form create) after redirect to the listing page, When you try to back to the dashboard or other page from listing
In this case you have to use

```
app.views.main.router.back({
                    url: '/your router where you want to go.../',
                    force: true,
                    ignoreCache: true
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

On f7 v8.3.2 (framework7-svelte) try:

```
app.f7.views.main.router.navigate("/route");
```

Don't forget to import app

```
import {app} from "framework7-svelte";
```